# WPF binding multiple UserControls to a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, user-controls, listbox

I have multiple UserControls and i want to show them on a ListBox
Lets assume i have an Employee abstract UserControl and i have 2 or more UserControls than use that Employee like AdministrativeEmployee and FactoryEmployee for each of those Employees i have diffrent data but the UserControl is very similar (same size, almost same fields), on the ViewModel side i have an abstract EmployeeViewModel, the AdministrativeEmployeeViewModel and the FatoryEmployeeViewModel, on the EmployeesView i have the ListBox with the databinding and on the EmployeesViewModel i have an ICollection Employees

EmployeesView.xaml:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Solution.Controls"
```

-

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Employees}>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Name="Presenter" />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger  Value="{x:Type local:AdministrativeEmployeeView}">
                        <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <local:AdministrativeEmployeeView />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Value="{x:Type local:FactoryEmployeeView}">
                        <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <local:FactoryEmployeeView/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

EmployeesViewModel.cs:

```
public ICollection<EmployeeViewModel> Employees { get; set; }
```

But that show me System.ItemTemplate on the ListBox and not the UserControls for each type of Employee

Comment: Is this a typo? `ItemsSource={Binding Employees}`should be `ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"`. And a DataTrigger without a Binding is useless.

Comment: It seems like you're using a very roundabout method here.  Why not just define DataTemplates with Type specified?  That will automagically render each type with its assigned template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `ListBox` resources define two DataTemplates:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AdministrativeEmployee}">
            <local:AdministrativeEmployeeView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FactoryEmployee}">
            <local:FactoryEmployeeView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>            
</ListBox>
```

Model classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }   
}

public class AdministrativeEmployee : Employee
{
}

public class FactoryEmployee : Employee
{
}
```

Sample data:

```
List<Employee> _source = new List<Employee>();
_source.Add(new AdministrativeEmployee { Name = "A test1" });
_source.Add(new FactoryEmployee { Name = "F test1" });
_source.Add(new AdministrativeEmployee { Name = "A test2" });
_source.Add(new FactoryEmployee { Name = "F test2" });
Employees = _source;
```

AdministrativeEmployeeView:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Red" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

FactoryEmployeeView:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Green" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It was pretty close to what i needed, anyway, i have to change few lines

    `xlmns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Solution.ViewModels"`

and change the DataTemplates to:

    `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AdministrativeEmployeeViewModel}">
        <local:AdministrativeEmployeeView />
    </DataTemplate>`